# Loop until a specific user input

Tags: python, loops, numbers

I am trying to write a number guessing program as follows:

```
def oracle():
    n = ' '
    print 'Start number = 50'
    guess = 50 #Sets 50 as a starting number
    n = raw_input("\n\nTrue, False or Correct?: ")
    while True:
        if n == 'True':
            guess = guess + int(guess/5)
            print
            print 'What about',guess, '?'
            break
        elif n == 'False':
            guess = guess - int(guess/5)
            print
            print 'What about',guess, '?'
            break
        elif n == 'Correct':
            print 'Success!, your number is approximately equal to:', guess

oracle()
```

What I am trying to do now is get this sequence of if/ elif/ else commands to loop until the user enters 'Correct', i.e. when the number stated by the program is approximately equal to the users number, however if I do not know the users number I cannot think how I could implement and if statement, and my attempts to use 'while' also do not work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As an alternative to @Mark Byers' approach, you can use `while True`:

```
guess = 50     # this should be outside the loop, I think
while True:    # infinite loop
    n = raw_input("\n\nTrue, False or Correct?: ")
    if n == "Correct":
        break  # stops the loop
    elif n == "True":
        # etc.
```

Comment: +1 similar to my update. I think the use of `input` here is also wrong.

Comment: @MarkByers: changed it to `raw_input`. From the looks of the `print` statements, the OP is using Python 2.

Comment: Could either of you tell me why the code now terminates after entering True or False?

Comment: Err... perhaps because you put a break statement there?! What exactly did you *think* would happen when it hit the break statement? Perhaps you should read a Python tutorial...

Comment: Sorry I'm being stupid, I have been up for too long haha, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't work because you haven't assigned anything to `n` before you first use it. Try this:

```
def oracle():
    n = None
    while n != 'Correct':
        # etc...
```

A more readable approach is to move the test until later and use a `break`:

```
def oracle():
    guess = 50

    while True:
        print 'Current number = {0}'.format(guess)
        n = raw_input("lower, higher or stop?: ")
        if n == 'stop':
            break
        # etc...
```

Also `input` in Python 2.x reads a line of input and then *evaluates* it. You want to use `raw_input`.

Note: In Python 3.x, `raw_input` has been renamed to `input` and the old `input` method no longer exists.

Comment: +1, though it would be more pythonic to use `None` to denote "no value".

Comment: Could either of you tell me why the code now terminates after entering True or False?