# Exception Handling in Python (Try...Except)

Tags: python, exception, try-except

I'm trying to implement the `try...except` exception handling into the code below.  When something like "s4" is entered, I want the output of "Non numeral value..." to appear.

Any idea on where I've gone wrong?

```
import string

import math

def getSqrt(n):
    return math.sqrt(float(n))

s = input("Enter a numerical value: ")

try:
    for i in s:
        if (i.isdigit() or i == "."):
            sType = "nonstr"

    if (sType =="nonstr"):
        print(getSqrt(s))

    else:
        s = "Non numberical value..."


except ValueError as ex:
    print(ex)


else:
    print(s)
```

Comment: you need to check your nonstr condition again.

Comment: also, if you are testing the string already, what exception do you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ask for forgiveness](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) - convert the entered value to `float` and handle `ValueError`:

```
try:
    s = float(input("Enter a numerical value: "))
except ValueError:
    print("Non numberrical value...")
else:
    print(getSqrt(s))
```

Demo:

```
>>> try:
...     s = float(input("Enter a numerical value: "))
... except ValueError:
...     print("Non numberrical value...")
... 
Enter a numerical value: s4
Non numberrical value...
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Excuse my confusion, but how do I implement this into the code above to still handle when an integer is entered and the square root is returned?  I shoud have explained ths further in my initial question.

Comment: @CoPoPHP just call `getSqrt()` after the try/except block. See I've updated the code in the answer.

Comment: @alacxe Should I be getting a Name Error now?  `NameError: name 's' is not defined`.  I'm not fully understanding this...

Comment: @CoPoPHP well, it depends on what are you planning to do on error. You can exit the program by calling `sys.exit()` or you can allow the user to enter the number again until there wouldn't be a `ValueError`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114355/loop-until-a-specific-user-input

Comment: @alacxe Thanks, let me take a look at the link.  Basically, I'm trying to either display the square root or the "Non numerical value...".

Comment: @CoPoPHP you can also put `getSqrt()` call under `else`.