# How do I make a loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started a pretty basic program in PyScripter using python3. I've asked the user to input a number and my program caculates the number. Thats all running well but I wondered if anyone know how to on python as the user if they want the program to run again or evit. If so how do I run the caculator again and how do I exit at there request. I.E "would you like to run the program again type yes or no* if yes how do I execute the same code again if no how to stop it from executing. Thanks fro your help.

```
Number = int(input("Number Required"))

 if Number >= 1 and Number<=50:
  add =(Number * 5)
  print("The Number amount it", add)

 elif Number <= 80 and Number >= 50:
   add =(Number * 4)
   print("The Number amount it", add)

 elif Number <= 100 and Number >= 80:
   add =(Number * 2.5)
   print("The Number amount it", add)

 run = input("would you like to check again type yes or no")
```

Comment: Add your code, before the question is closed .... Hurry up

Comment: How much did you research this before asking? There's a lot of [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8114405/2498729) on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add all of your code inside a `while` loop

```
repeat = True
while repeat:
    Number = int(input("Number Required"))

    if Number >= 1 and Number<=50:
      add =(Number * 5)
      print("The Number amount it", add)

    elif Number <= 80 and Number >= 50:
       add =(Number * 4)
       print("The Number amount it", add)

    elif Number <= 100 and Number >= 80:
       add =(Number * 2.5)
       print("The Number amount it", add)

    run = input("would you like to check again type yes or no")
    if run == 'no': repeat = False
```

*Small Tip*

Instead of having a long comparison like `Number >= 1 and Number<=50` you can instead do as Padraic [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174906/how-to-run-again-and-terminate-program-from-user-input-in-python/28175056?noredirect=1#comment44719520_28175056) which is `1 <= Number <= 50`. It is easier and more readable.

Comment: `if 1 <= Number <= 50`, you can also  just use `while True` and `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Once a process finishes it cannot start itself - it needs another process or service to start it again but from how you presented your issue you just need to loop over the some logic without exiting the process.

Updating my answer as you updated the question

```
while True:
    x = input("Enter your input: \n")
    some_logic_here()
```

Comment: FYI: this will fail with a NameError on Python3, which is what the OP is using.

Comment: Have missed that he is on python3. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simply calculator program that has the kind of function I believe you're looking for here: https://github.com/ArnoldM904/Random_Programs/blob/master/Python_Programs/BlackBox_Area%26Volume.py

To keep it simple though one (of many options) would be to make a basic Restart() function.

The Restart() function I call after a calculation in my example:

```
def Restart():
    toMenu = raw_input("\nTo go back to main menu, type '1'. To exit, type '2'.\n\n")
    if toMenu == '1':
        menu() # My menu function
    elif toMenu == '2':
        exit() # Built-in Python Exit-program option
    else:
        invalid() # My "Invalid input" error message
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a single prompt that covers all the possibilities

```
while True:
    answer = input("Enter number or 'q' to exit")
    if answer == 'q':
        break
    try:
        Number = int(answer)
    except ValueError:
        print("'{}' is not a number".format(answer))
        continue
    ... your calculator here ...
```