# PYTHON program is refusing to loop

Tags: python

I have this code pasted below, essentially I'm trying to make it loop If the user inputs in an invalid test score(cause lets face it you cant have a negative test score or a score over 100%). So essentially I'm trying to have the program loop if they do enter an invalid score and do so until they enter one that is within the range of 0 to a 100(inclusive).

Code:

```
A='A'

B="B"

C="C"

D="D"

F="F"

score=float(input("Enter a test score: "))

def determine_grade(score):
    while score >= 0 and score < 100:
        if score >=90 and score <=100:
            print(A)

        elif score >=80 and score <=89:
            print(B)

        elif score >=70 and score <=79:
            print(C)

        elif score >=60 and score <=69:
            print(D)

        elif score < 60:
            print(F)
        
        return score

    score = float(input("Invalid score range, please input it again: "))

    
determine_grade(score)
```

so far my output looks like this:

> Enter a test score: -2
>
> Invalid score range, please input it again: -2

and then it stops there, I need it to continue to loop until I get a value that's between the 0 and 100(inclusive)

Comment: Sure it does, you return after the first iteration

Comment: @61612: Hu? I don't know how it even makes it into the loop.

Comment: As @61612 said, check the indentation level for `return score`.

Comment: If you're using Python 2, you should replace `input` with `raw_input`.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier the final line in the script is a call to `determine_grade(score) `

Comment: @aruisdante: This doesn't look like `do .. while`.

Comment: So your saying put return score after my score=input statement?

Comment: @BenjaminBannier It's not, they assign to `score` based on user input before the function definition. However in our hast to answer their immediate question (which was caused by a typo), we missed the larger problem of what they were trying to actually *do* with this function: prompt for user input until some correct input is provided. This question is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114355/loop-until-a-specific-user-input and many other similar. The answers that were provided before the lock caught this.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The programming problem the OP has is one that many rookies have which is to determine how control statements affect program flow. This problem might have been averted by `programming by intention` and can be illustrated when I edit my answer to refactor the one function into several explaining functions.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `raw_input()` Python 2.x or `input()` Python 3.x to get values from user.
2. Do **exception** handling for `ValueError` if user enters a nonnumerical value.
3. Do **Type casting** from `string` to `float`.
4. Validate user input is in between `0` and `100`.
5. If 2 and 4 are True then do not break loop, ask again to enter valid number.
6. **break statement** will exit `while` loop i.e. code comes out of respective loop.
7. Use `if` and `elif` loop to print class according to user input.

code:

```
A='A'
B="B"
C="C"
D="D"
F="F" 

def determine_grade():
    while 1:
        try:
            score = float(raw_input("Enter score: "))
            if score < 0 or score > 100:
                print "Number in between 0 and 100"
            else:
                break
        except ValueError:
            print "Wrong input. Only float numbers"

    if score >=90 and score <=100:
        print(A)
    elif score >=80 and score <=89:
        print(B)
    elif score >=70 and score <=79:
        print(C)
    elif score >=60 and score <=69:
        print(D)
    elif score < 60:
        print(F)
    return score

determine_grade()
```

output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 28.py
Enter score: we
Wrong input. Only float numbers
Enter score: -8
Number in between 0 and 100
Enter score: 101
Number in between 0 and 100
Enter score: 56
F
```

Comment: @Cristian Ciupitu: Thanx. more clear. Apology to grammar and spelling mistakes. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have your detailed tests within the while loop.  Then while loop should be used to get a valid score:

```
score=float(input("Enter a test score: "))

def determine_grade(score):
    while score < 0 or score > 100:
        score = float(input("Invalid score range, please input it again: "))

    if score >=90 and score <=100:
        print('A')

    elif score >=80 and score <=89:
        print('B')

    elif score >=70 and score <=79:
        print('C')

    elif score >=60 and score <=69:
        print('D')

    elif score < 60:
        print('F')

    return score

determine_grade(score)
```

**Edit:**

Lets move stuff around (aka [refactoring](http://www.refactoring.com/))

Lets move the main program statements together:

```
def enter_and_validate_test_score():
    score = float(input("Enter a test score: "))
    determine_grade(score)

enter_and_validate_test_score()
```

But the `determine_grade` function is the wrong name for what it does.

The procedure should be to get a valid score first, then print the grade based on that score:

```
def enter_and_validate_test_score():
    score = float(input("Enter a test score: "))
    score = validate_score(score)
    print_grade(score)
```

This leaves us with `validate_score` and `print_grade`

```
def validate_score(score):
    while score < 0 or score > 100:
        score = float(input("Invalid score range, please input it again: "))
    return score    

def determine_grade(score):
    if score >= 90 and score <= 100:
        print('A')

    elif score >= 80 and score <= 89:
        print('B')

    elif score >= 70 and score <= 79:
        print('C')

    elif score >= 60 and score <= 69:
        print('D')

    else:
        print('F')
```

Also note the final `else:`

So finally the whole program is:

```
def validate_score(score):
    while score < 0 or score > 100:
        score = float(input("Invalid score range, please input it again: "))
    return score    

def determine_grade(score):
    if score >= 90 and score <= 100:
        print('A')

    elif score >= 80 and score <= 89:
        print('B')

    elif score >= 70 and score <= 79:
        print('C')

    elif score >= 60 and score <= 69:
        print('D')

    else:
        print('F')

def enter_and_validate_test_score():
    score = float(input("Enter a test score: "))
    score = validate_score(score)
    print_grade(score)

enter_and_validate_test_score()
```